# urllib2 load part of compressed page

Tags: python, urllib2

I need analogue:

```
urllib2.urlopen(url).read(100)
```

But for compressed pages, like:

```
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
buf = StringIO(response.read(100))
gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='r').read()

IOError: CRC check failed 0xd71b7369L != 0x0L
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [**zlib**](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) library instead.  Gzip relies on zlib, but introduces file-level compression concept along with CRC checking, and it seems like this is not what you want.

See this good [HTTP Compression in python](http://jython.xhaus.com/http-compression-in-python-and-jython/) article (although the article mentions not to use zlib directly, you should try both and base your decision of which to use off of what you are specifically trying to do and what works best for *you*) as well as these [**code snippets from Dough Hellman** which show how to compress or decompress with zlib](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/zlib/index.html).

---

Some good reading material:

- [**RFC 1952**](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html) - details about the GZIP format
- [`zlib` Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it is possible to do this, as you need the full GZIP file (10+ byte header, body, 8 byte footer) to extract it. Unless you have it completely, you cannot extract it. And as your error message explains, the CRC check fails, as the CRC is in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the server to only send you the first 100 bytes (using the `Range` header):

```
import urllib2

req=urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/')
#
# Here we request that bytes 0--100 be downloaded.
# The range is inclusive, and starts at 0.
#
req.add_header('Accept-encoding','gzip')
req.add_header('Range','bytes={}-{}'.format(0, 99))
f=urllib2.urlopen(req)
# This shows you the actual bytes that have been downloaded.
content_range=f.headers.get('Content-Range')
print(content_range)
# bytes 0-99/18716
print(repr(f.read()))
# '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtm'
```

Comment: Good idea, but for addition only. I need client-side size control.